# Avro - Handling an array of complex types with multiple schemas

Tags: avro

I'm creating an Avro Schema to represent my object and I'm wondering what's the proper way to handle an array that can contains multiple structures. As example, my object look like this JSON:

```
{
      "id": 665534346251,      
      "events": [
        {
          "id": 665534346314,
          "type": "Comment",
          "author_id": 377633942574,
          "body": "x.",
          "html_body": "x",
          "plain_body": "x.",
          "public": true,
          "attachments": [],
          "audit_id": 665534346251
        },
        {
          "id": 665534346394,
          "type": "Create",
          "value": "a",
          "field_name": "subject"
        },
        {
          "id": 665534346454,
          "type": "Create",
          "value": [
            "xn",
            "x",
            "a"
          ],
          "field_name": "tags"
        }]}
```

Is possible to represent "events" and avro choose what schema fits for each object?

Answer (score 0):

You could make one object if you include fields, but make some optional via union definitions.

Taking the posted example, see the bottom two fields

```
      "id": 665534346314,
      "type": "Comment",
      "author_id": 377633942574,
      "body": "x.",
      "html_body": "x",
      "plain_body": "x.",
      "public": true,
      "attachments": [],
      "audit_id": 665534346251
      "field_name": union<null, string> 
      "value": union<null, array>
```

Make a string value a single valued list.

Comment: Ya but I still need to add fields like `body`, `html_body` and go on for each event, right? Isn't possible to create separated schemas for each object?

Comment: You can create separate schemas, sure, but Avro wouldn't "choose" that for you